# Ajax auto-load by counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got this code from some template, it gets executed by clicking on the tabs to fetch posts into the page. All I want is to have an edited copy of this code to fetch posts by **timer** aside from clicking on the tabs. [I have tried the `setInterval`   but it didn't work](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18253566#18253566), I appreciate any help I am so new to Ajax and JQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    setInterval(function(){

        e.preventDefault();
        var bt = $(this);
        var bts = bt.parent().parent();
        var where = $(this).parent().parent().parent().next();
        var nbs = bt.parent().parent().data('nbs');
        var nop = bt.parent().parent().data('number_of_posts');

        cat = bt.data('cat_id');
        if (cat === '') {
            cat = bt.data('parent_cat');
        }
        where.parent().find('.show-more').find('.nomoreposts').remove();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: nbtabs.url,
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: "action=nbtabs&nonce="+nbtabs.nonce+"&cat="+cat+"&nbs="+nbs+"&number_of_posts="+nop,
            cach: false,
            beforeSend : function () {
                where.parent().append('<i class="nb-load"></i>');
            },
            success: function(data){
                where.hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                bts.find('li').removeClass('active');
                bt.parent().addClass('active');
                where.parent().find('.nb-load').remove();
            }
        });
    }, 5000)

})
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of your current progress for easy debugging? Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelSanchez Actually my progress is nothing I have leak of experience on jQuery methods.

Comment: His attempt with `setInterval`: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18253566#18253566

Comment: You can write a function for popup and use setInterval to call it after a delay ..

Answer (score 1):

You have to get started to some degree before we can really help you code-wise. We can't just write the code for you because we do not know what elements you want updated and how.

All I can advise you is the Jquery Ajax method is how this code retrieves url responses:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<name of your url or maybe servlet>"
        success: function(data){
           // data is the response from your url
           // in the code sample, data was html that was inserted to an element
        }
    });
```

You can put this ajax call in a function and use `setInterval`. You can place the `setInterval` call on your `Jquery.ready()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is that you're trying to call `jQuery.setInterval`, not `setInterval`. `jQuery.setInterval` is not a function, so calling it will just give you an error.

The next issue is that your script tries to alter a bunch of elements, using the clicked element as a starting point. This is bad practice because of situations like this, where changing how to function is invoked can completely break the script. Without knowing what all of this:

```
var bt = $(this);
var bts = bt.parent().parent();
var where = $(this).parent().parent().parent().next();
var nbs = bt.parent().parent().data('nbs');
var nop = bt.parent().parent().data('number_of_posts');
```

is, it's pretty difficult to give advice. The safest bet is to replace `$(this)` with `jQuery(".nb-tabbed-head li a")`, but that might cause issues because `$(this)` refers to only one element, whereas `jQuery(".nb-tabbed-head li a")` may refer to multiple.

Really the biggest issue is that you're trying to use code that a) is poorly-written and b) you don't understand yet. I highly recommend learning about AJAX, events, the DOM, and jQuery before you make a serious attempt at this. It's almost impossible to create a good product when you're gluing together pieces of code that you don't understand that were written by someone that you don't know.

Comment: Thank you that's really good advice but I thought that my problem is easy to use.. just change the event from on-click to counter.